# How can I prevent tilde in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to block the possibility to type a tilde `~` in my input.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
$('#myInput').on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 192) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.keyCode);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myInput" />
```

I tried the same as above with `keydown`, `keypressed`, `keyup`, but it is not working as intended.
Do anyone got a simple solution?

Comment: yes (~) i want block posiblity to type tilde in my Input

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using? Are you sure it requires the shift key to be pressed? On my german keyboard it is "Alt Gr"+"+": `if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 187)`.

Comment: @31piy if you twice type tilde then second one is visible

Comment: *I tried keydown, keypressed, keyup* - If you're not sure if the event handler is working then add a `console.log(e.keyCode)` inside (or other for the other events).

Comment: @PatrykKubacki, is this question closed, or are you still waiting for other answers?

Answer (score 4):

Some people say your code works, some people don't.

Because, "~" isn't binded on the same keys on each keyboard layout.
To be able to block the possibility of writing (or pasting) "~" for everyone, I'll do something like this:

```js
$('#myInput').on("keyup", function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/~/g, '');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" />
```

We can see the "~" character been deleted each time we try to insert one, but I don't think that's an issue. Instead, I think that will help the user understand he can't use that character, without doubting about the good-functioning of their keyboard.
It's possible to use `input` instead of `keyup` to avoid that behaviour, but I personally prefer it that way for the above reasons.

⋅ ⋅ ⋅

This would be possible to add some other forbidden characters by modifying the regex:

```js
$('#myInput').on("keyup", function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[~^!]/g, '');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" />
<p>Forbidden: ~ ^ !</p>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It also moves the caret to the end, which is pretty annoying, but shows the principal.

Comment: I edited with a regular expression, because I was able to put many "~" when letting the key pressed, and only one was replaced.